# Конвертация кода с использованием tensorflow из py в exe с помощью pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, tensorflow

Возник вопрос по конвертации кода с использованием tensorflow из py в exe с помощью pyinstaller. Сама по себе конвертация проходит без проблем и ошибок, но при запуске EXEшника выскакивает ошибка

[image: ошибка]

полный текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rustui.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\python\saved_model\saved_model.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\python\saved_model\builder.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\python\saved_model\builder_impl.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py", line 37, in <module>
TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
    () -> handle
```

как я прочитал, это связано с тем, что tenserflow имеет много зависимостей, и pyinstaller все их не устанавливает. При этом не нашел ни одного понятного обьяснения, как это пофиксить. Буду очень благодарен, если у вас получиться мне помочь.

Comment: [Вот это](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib/) должно помочь.

Comment: Вы при помощи тензорфлоу создали некую модель? ... если да, то можно рассмотреть вариант её пиклеризации, это должно помочь с завертыванием её и уже после этого подготовить exe